# How do I delete from multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have two arrays sitting inside an object, and a function to delete an item from an array specified by the user.

```
var warehouse{
  shirts: [],
  shorts: [],

  deleteItem: function(itemType, itemNumber){
    this.itemType.splice(itemNumber, 1);
  }
}
```

So, if I do something like:

```
function('shirts', 0);
```

It should delete the first item in the 'shirts' array. Problem is, it is telling me that itemType is coming up as `undefined`

Comment: Your syntax is off - `var warehouse = { `, and `warehouse.deleteItem('shirts', 0);`, for starters. Beyond that, when you're trying to use a variable as an array key like this, try `this[itemType]` rather than `this.itemType`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```js
var warehouse = {
  shirts: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  shorts: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  deleteItem: function(itemType, itemNumber){
    this[itemType].splice(itemNumber, 1);
  }
};

warehouse.deleteItem("shirts", 0);
console.log(warehouse);
```